# Laravel Scope Querying and Displaying with Count

Tags: laravel

User.php

```
public function queryCountusers($query){
    $query->where(['confirmation' => true])->whereIn('role_id', [2, 3])->count();
}
```

UserController.php

```
public function index() {
    // $users = App\User::popular()->active()->orderBy('created_at')->get();
    $count_user = User::countusers();
    return view('admin.index', compact('count_user'));
}
```

main.blade.php

```
<div class="tile-stats tile-red">
    <div class="icon"><i class="entypo-users"></i></div>
    <div class="num" data-start="0" data-end="{{$count_user}}" data-postfix="" data-duration="1500" data-delay="0">0</div>
    <h3>Registered users</h3>
    <p>so far in our blog, and our website.</p>
</div>
```

The problem is I'm having an error of:

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::countusers()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to use `scopes`, then

Change

```
public function queryCountusers($query){
        $query->where(['confirmation' => true])->whereIn('role_id', [2, 3])->count();
    }
```

to

```
public function scopeCountusers($query){
        return $query->where(['confirmation' => true])->whereIn('role_id', [2, 3])->count();
    }
```

Comment: Yes sir, Error is still there.

Comment: I just didn't use scopes this time. Thanks

Comment: No i don't use your approach just the traditional DB